# Hex Data In Linux from SQL Server 2008 Not in correct format in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache, laravel-5

When I query hex image data in PHP from Sql server in Linux, the data is different from what I get in Windows. ALso im unable to use hex2bin in Linux, I am able to convert it windows and display the image perfectly where as the data in Linux shows up something like below and is non readable and hex2bin throws up some even digit error.

```
����JFIF``��C         $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���
```

How can I get the correct data. The data type in SQL server is Image and data is stored in hex format like this 0xFFF

Comment: Can you attach your laravel error log? You can find it on `laravel_project/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" is just a generic text for public display. You need to find the actual error message in your logs. If it happens to be an Apache error it'll be at `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`.

Comment: Thank you I got the error in the laravel logs, but was not showing up in the response